# push_back a PRvalue into a vector

Tags: c++11, move-semantics, rvalue-reference, rvalue, xvalue

Carefully reading the references,
A move constructor can only be called by a Xvalue.
Then, how something like...

`std::vector<Class> vec
vec.push_back(Class(..args..))`

is possible without moving(casting) it to an Xvalue?
Is there a specific way to use move semantics on PRvalues?

Comment: move semantics were invented for (p)rvalues. I think you were referring to the intro of http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor - it has now been updated.

Comment: also note your example doesn't match your question title: where is  the push_back?

Comment: Ah sorry. Seems like I made a mistake. I'll edit it